# Why would a compiled and linked high-level language execute slower than Assembly/machine code?

Tags: c, binary-files

Say I compile and link C in to a flat binary or some executable output format to run on a bare machine. If I optimized and fed the direct binary to the CPU upon boot up, why would the resulted format take more clock cycles from a compiled and linked C origin than just Assembly assembled? What I mean is that if the same instructions are fed and fetched from some binary format, regardless of the origin, if the resulting binary yields the same opcodes whether from C, D, Assembly or even direct written opcodes themself (if possible), why do programmers often say that Assembly will always be faster?

Sorry if not clear, but in general, shouldn't the same fetched opcodes take the same clock cycles and CPU resources regardless of the origin, if linked and/or compiled/assembled, if the binary file contains only the necessary instructions (and a linker script or output format handler can do this for C or such, it should be just as fast).

Comment: This question would be more suited for Stack Overflow

Comment: You are probably right. Could you vote it to move there?

Comment: @Dinosaurpawz: Might want to check first if your questions haven't already been addressed there. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577554/when-is-assembler-faster-than-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239144/how-is-assembly-faster-than-hlls etc.

Comment: Yeah, but my question pertains to bare metal, not just benchmarks for application software.

Comment: Your whole question is based on a faulty premise.  It is simply not true that assembly language is always faster than a compiled program.  But *some* algorithms can be coded more efficiently in assembly language than a high-level language.  For example multi-word arithmetic or bit manipulation: assembly language can utilize the **carry bit** for efficiency whereas a high-level language would have to have code expressions using a temp variable.

Comment: Please provide a reference to where programmers say "Assembly will always be faster".

Comment: @sawdust: "assembly language can utilize the carry bit for efficiency whereas a high-level language would have to have code expressions using a temp variable." That doesn't seem to make for a compelling argument. Any reason why the compiler can't suitably optimise to use the carry bit too (as Ken sort of stated in his answer)?

Comment: I don't need to; I'm just recalling what I've witnessed from some. Either way, it makes for a good question for others as well.

Comment: @Karan - That was a quick recollection of some functions that were rewritten in assembly language in some past projects.  Admittedly the compilers used were not that good (IIRC in one project I reported to the vender 3 compiler bugs that generated faulty code).  Maybe a good, modern optimizing compiler can do a much better job.  But I was just trying to come up with a balanced argument.

Comment: To refute your premise, here's [info on a compiler for the ARM Cortex-A8 with NEON SIMD](https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/omap/optimization/arm_cortex_a8) that claims that following certain *"guidelines will significantly speed up your code and will perform equally to hand crafted assembler in most cases"* and that with use of the ARM NEON instruction set *"in 90% of the cases the compiler will generate better code than hand-crafted assembler instructions"*.

Answer (score 6):

Your premise is faulty. If you used a high-level language that compiled down to a flat binary with the exact same opcodes as hand-crafted assembler, then that program would execute exactly the same. The problem is, those conditions never really happen.

Every C program has bootstrap code at the beginning (before you get to main), so right away there are extra opcodes. If you call a function, C calling conventions could be less optimized than specialized assembly calls, which can vary by function. Finally, the opcodes generated by a compiler inside any given function are different than hand-assembler; sometimes better and sometimes worse, depending on the ability of the compiler writers versus the assembly programmer. So "assembly is always better" is not true either.

For example, a compiler might unroll a loop to make it faster. In assembler, you might do the same thing with a macro; but would the assembly programmer go to that trouble?

Comment: You can always use C without any statically linked libraries; for example, no #include, and just start at a main function. Assuming this outputs to a flat binary, and there is only one starting function/label, boilerplate code would not be required for anything really as far as I know. That main function can declare a pointer or integer to video memory, and addresses can be specifically output as literal values since no virtual memory would be existent(in my example).

Comment: No: C startup and exit code does many things; e.g. [embedded ARM](http://www.bravegnu.org/gnu-eprog/c-startup.html), [Linux x86](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html). A C program that just does `return 0;` from main will typically be at least a few KB. (And if you leave out the `return`, many flavors of C will implicitly add that for you to conform to the standard.) Now, someone could write a "super-optimizing" compiler/linker that notices you "don't use anything" and leave all that stuff out, but again, that's theory, not practice.

Comment: Do you have evidences?

Comment: Links are in my comment. Also, trying compiling an empty C program yourself. Some of the resulting file is due to PE/ELF/Mach-O/etc executable format; but even a DOS .COM -- a flat binary image -- will be a few hundred or thousand bytes to do "nothing".

Comment: Linking it to a flat binary, not a DOS COM format, but only the output opcodes with no added bytes, but I guess you're right. Writing in opcodes directly assures no unnecessary stack setup or other opcodes I won't be needing, so I will just code my system software in opcodes directly. Thanks for your time and help, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

A well-written assembly program will run faster than a comparable C program simply because the assembly program will not have all the boilerplate code that the C program would for things such as saving and restoring CPU or stack state.

Comment: But if writing for a bare machine you would need no headers or boilerplate code; you'd need to assure that the output is _direct executable_.

Comment: the issue is primarily that the compiler cannot completely optimize when it builds the assembly, and as a result, some extra code at the assembly level may occur. For instance, the compiler has to treat all for loops (or categories thereof) the same, so the compiled representation of the structure may include items that that particular loop did not require.

Comment: @Dinosaurpawz: Few people write to the bare metal; most programming is done to an OS.

Comment: I must write to the bare metal; I write system software, nkt just application software for an OS. My point was not in comparison at thay level, but at the architecture itself, if optimized efficiently.

Comment: It is not true that a well-written assembly program will not have "boilerplate" code, like saving registers or stack state. Many assembly APIs allow subroutines and macros to use registers, so a caller must save them. Also, most assembly APIs require prologues to set up a consistent state.

Comment: @DourHighArch: It will have code for saving and restoring registers. It will not have the same code for saving and restoring registers per function regardless of whether or not it's required.

Comment: Doug, I was talking in regards to C code that is not statically linked with any library, has only one entry point (or function), and begins execution right at kernelMain(); or such. Saving registers or the stack state would be done by the compiler, but a specialized linker script can assure that the code is a headerless binary, or a specific output format handling program that only releases certain binary to be executed, leaving out most of the boilerplate code in a normal C program.

Answer (score 0):

Faster is good at algorithms. Inline codes as inserts in the assembler will be better and faster. If you can spend unlimited time in search of undocumented instructions, for example, will see instantaneous calculation of quadratic sums in one action presents and other oddities ... All depends on the compatibility and during the writing of programs. The second point multi-core and multi-processor, the algorithm should be good for the simultaneous execution of multiple processor cores. There is enough technology, when actions are made in advance. Such as full-text search - long work, but you see instantaneous results within fractions of a second. There is one thing that is falsely taken for the performance of the software - the responsiveness of the system. You can do the work asynchronously or in part, to satisfy a user's query gradually, it often physically unable to immediately process the amount of information given away. Or simply lose interest in it based on some criteria. You, in turn, save the resources of the performance and responsiveness of the system.

Well, there is nothing better than testing for a specific situation and good libraries)).

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Dinosaurpawz Oh, there are many answers to various questions, including your). Are you looking for speed? About speed is the answer. About why assembly language faster? Usually it depends on the skills and knowledge of the programmer. If he writes the code better than the standard units that produces `C` and assembly code in between, yes. Or should that standard or not, and again we get back to training. In the light of further your questions I think you need a compiler assembler source code for different processors. There are answers. http://flatassembler.net/download.php

Comment: I wasn't looking for speed, I was just asking why some programmers state that Assembly is always faster when C can compare, even D.

Comment: Myth and a bit of the truth. Qualifications assembler programmers 20 years ago was often better than the higherlevel language programmers. They understood how the compiler works and what it does in detail. How do these or other language constructs. Yes, in a certain time, it was virtually taken for granted that the code is working in assembly language is typically 20-30% faster, but much more is very costly in time by 80%. See for example the book Tom Swan Turbo Assembler 2nd Edition. When the performance was worth less time programmers, all switched to inline assembly in highlevel languages.

Answer (score 0):

For a quite long time now, compilers routinely outperform competent assembly programmers. For extremely time-critical, very short code stretches, an expert programmer might do better if tuning carefully for a few days worth of work.